# How do I execute Calculus operations in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, calculus

How can I perform simple calculus operations on python such as Differentiation and Integration?

Comment: Take a look at simpy package.  It provides functionalities for symbolic math operations like differentiation and integration.  If numeric calculus is what you are looking for, you can still use simpy package, but numpy and scipy would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sympy` module for symbolic manipulation. The `scipy` module has both differentiation and integration as well. See https://www.scipy.org/ and https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the math module has a way to do calculus as such, but there is a library to do a good amount of differentiation and integration.

The library name is sympy. Here is the link to the tutorial page: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html

Alternatively, if you only want to do differentiation, tensorflow can also do it for you, however, I would use the sympy library since it is easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about exact code implementations, but I think your best bet would be to try using the popular Python package [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and various [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) packages . [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) is documentation for doing Integration, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Below Link will help i hope you can use

`import sympy as sym`

[click here for help: sympy library](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/sympy.html)

***thanks***

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SymPy library for Python
The below code will do simple differentiation and you can expand upon it to perform more complex calculus

```
 from SymPy import *
 x = symbols('x')
 diff(exp(x**2), x)
```

For more information check out
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't exp() function require the math module?

Comment: SymPy also has a built in exp() funtion that has the same function.